# Microsoft guidelines for creating WPF "gel" buttons

Tags: button, wpf-controls

Anyone know where I can find the Microsoft guidelines for creating WPF gel-type buttons? I'm not sure if "gel" is the correct name for this effect but I have heard many people use the term. If MS doesn't have a guideline, do you have some other standards or guidelines for creating these buttons?

Comment: I can't see how you imagine this guidelines?

Comment: Reminds me of a great thing I saw years ago on LonghornBlogs back then when WPF was called Avalon and was a largely different beast...

Comment: When MS creates these buttons for use in their apps they must have some guidelines, or probably standards, for how they need to look. That's what I want to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [glass button](http://blogs.conchango.com/johnrayner/archive/2006/12/22/WPF_2F00_E_3A00_-A-glass-button.aspx).

> There are a number of XAML elements
>   which go into making up the button. 
>   They are clearly commented in the XAML
>   but the list is as follows:
>
> - Drop-shadow: an ellipse with a radial gradient of black fading to
>     tranparent
> - Button surround: a white ellipse slightly bigger than the green one
> - Black button background: only visible round the edges of the green
>     when the button is pressed
> - Main button colour: the green (or whatever color you want) of the
>     button.  This ellipse is clipped to
>     its initial outline, thus allowing us
>     to move the ellipse slightly for the
>     button press without it overlapping
>     the button surround
> - Top glow: an ellipse with a linear gradient background of white (at the
>     top) fading to transparent.  Smaller
>     than the main button colour and
>     positioned so that the tops are the
>     same
> - Bottom glow: an ellipse the same size as the main button colour but
>     with a linear gradient background of
>     white (at the bottom) fading to
>     transparent.  This is also clipped as
>     per the main button colour.
> - Hover-over glow: an ellipse the same size as the main button colour
>     with a radial gradient background of
>     white (at the centre of the ellipse)
>     fading to transparent.  This is
>     initially transparent.
> - Transparent element for catching mouse events: on top of all of this is
>     a transparent ellipse the same size as
>     the white button surround for catching
>     MouseEnter, MouseLeave,
>     MouseLeftButtonDown and
>     MouseLeftButtonUp events.  This
>     element also contains the Storyboard
>     for the pulsating hover-over effect
>     (although this could be in any XAML
>     element).